# opening a txt file twice c++

Tags: sorting, c++11, io

In my program I am trying to read a file of numbers. I would like to take the first number and make that number the size of my array. After closing the file, I would like to reopen the same file and store the rest of the numbers into the array. In the array, I would like to sort the numbers using the bubble sort algorithm and display the array in ascending order.

```
int readData(int * arr);
void bsort(int * arr, int last);
void writeToConsole(int * arr, int last);
void swap(int, int);
int main()
{
   ifstream inFile("data.txt");
   int arrSize;
   inFile >> arrSize;
   int * arr = new int[arrSize];
   inFile.close();
   readData(arr);
   writeToConsole(arr, arrSize);
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
int readData(int * arr)
{
   ifstream read("data.txt");
   int index = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       read >> *(arr + index);
       index++;
   }
   read.close();
   return *arr;
}
void bsort(int * arr, int last)
{
    for (int i = last - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            //this block is constant with respect to array size
            if (*(arr + (j - 1)) > *(arr + j))
            {
                int temp = *(arr + (j - 1));
                *(arr + (j - 1)) = *(arr + j);
                *(arr + j) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
void writeToConsole(int * arr, int last)
{
    bsort(arr, last);
    for (int i = 0; i < last; i++)
    {
        cout << *(arr + i) << " ";
    }
}
void swap(int x, int  y)
{
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}
```

In other words, the first time I read the file, the number that is stored will represent the size of my array. The second time I read the file, I want to skip the first number and proceed to the next one. When reading a file, how can I skip the first number? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the information from the file I would like to read:

```
9

8

4

7

2

9

5

6

1

3
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to read a file, read in a size, then close it, then open it again, skip the size, and read the contents. But it's an odd thing to do. Most people would open the file, read the size, allocate space for the data, read the data, and then close the file.

In C it is usually handy to know the size of a file's data a chunk before you read it. In C++ it is far less important as the std::vector class expands for you, doing all the fiddly memory reallocation behind the scenes.

The extraction and insertion operators << >> in C++ are arguably slightly easier to use than the C versions when everything goes right. When they go wrong, it is harder to understand what has gone wrong. Generally I advise newbies to use fopen and fgets() to read files line by line. That way you don't get confused by missing or skipped characters. The function sscanf() will then convert an ascii string to a number, but you can also print out the line whilst debugging to work out what is going on.

Comment: Any tips on how to allocate the space and then read the data? I'm thinking of creating another pointer variable, but I don't think that would be very effective. Advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is much more recommended to use all the potential of the C++ language and the Standard Library, after all you are using C++ instead C language. There are a tons of ways to do what you want. Depends on the format of the data stored in the file. But in all cases the Standard Library provide you with a plethora of functions and utilities to do not reinvent the wheel and keep focus in your real problem. In my case I come up with this solution for this particular I/O case. At the end my strong recommendation is: go to the documentation and try to find something that may made your work more simple

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> read_data( const string file_name){

  ifstream inf(file_name);

  istream_iterator<int> eoi, input(inf);

  vector<int> arr(*input++);//take the first integer, the size, and advance the iterator

  copy(input, eoi, arr.begin());

  return arr;
}

void bsort( vector<int>& data ){
  //sort data like you want
  sort( data.begin(), data.end());
}

void write_to_console( vector<int>& data){
  //do your stuff
  copy(data.begin(), data.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
}

int main(void) {
  string file_name = "data.txt";

  auto data = read_data( file_name );

  bsort( data );
  write_to_console( data );

  return 0;
}
```